# How not to refresh screen when swipe

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing an application in which I show a list of potatoes, retrieving the data from Firestore.

I have added a swipe action to refresh the data. With the code that I show below, the data is updating fine, the call is made to Firestore and it is updated showing new values ​​in case they exist, or stopping showing values ​​that no longer exist.

The problem is that when I swipe the potato list screen remains blank, empty, and when the call to Firestore ends, they are shown again. That is, there are a couple of seconds that the screen goes blank.

Is there a possibility that this will not happen? This effect is somewhat ugly

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class PotatoesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getPotatoesDataUseCase: GetPotatoesData
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = mutableStateOf(PotatoesState())
    val state: State<PotatoesState> = _state
    private val _isRefreshing = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isRefreshing: StateFlow<Boolean>
        get() = _isRefreshing.asStateFlow()

    init {
        getPotatoes()
    }

    private fun getPotatoes() {

        getPotatoesDataUseCase().onEach { result ->
            when (result) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    _state.value = PotatoesState(potatoes = result.data?.potatoes ?: emptyList())
                }
                is Resource.Error   -> {
                    _state.value = PotatoesState(
                        error = result.message ?: "An unexpected error occurred"
                    )
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    _state.value = PotatoesState(isLoading = true)
                }
            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }

    fun refresh() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _isRefreshing.emit(true)
            getIncidents()
            _isRefreshing.emit(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Screen:

```
@Composable
fun PotatoesDataScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: PotatoesViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val state = viewModel.state.value
    val isRefreshing by viewModel.isRefreshing.collectAsState()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(
                        stringResource(R.string.app_name),
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
                },
                backgroundColor = Primary,
                contentColor = Color.White
            )
        },

        content = {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

                SwipeRefresh(
                    state = rememberSwipeRefreshState(isRefreshing),
                    onRefresh = { viewModel.refresh() }
                ) {

                    LazyColumn(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
                    ) {
                        items(state.potatoes) { potato ->
                            PotatoCard(
                                potato = potato
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )

}
```

PotatoState:

```
data class PotatoesState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val potatoes: List<Potato> = emptyList(),
    val error: String = ""
)
```

Comment: What code does your `PotatoesState` have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the list screen is blank, this is the time when the Api call is made.
When your call is made and response is still not received, this is also when the list is blank.
You pass a new Object of `PotatoesState` to the `mutableState` every time you:

1. receive a response,
2. get an error, (with `Potatoes = emptyList()`)
3. or state is loading. (with `Potatoes = emptyList()`)

UI is updated according to the `MutableState` you named `_state`.

If you want to keep the same data until you get a new response, then you need to update the current `state.value: MutableState<PotatoesState>` object only when you get a new response (AKA, `is Resource.success`).

Alternatively, you can implement a Loading Spinner, and show it when you start your Api Request, until `isLoading` is `false`.

### **EDIT:** Addition of suggested code.

So that how I would declare **`PotatoesState`** class:

```kotlin
class PotatoesState(
    var isLoading: Boolean = false,
    var potatoes: List<Potato> = emptyList(),
    var error: String = ""
)
```

And that's what I would write in the CallBack function:

```kotlin
when (result) {
    is Resource.Success -> {
        if (result.data != null) {
            _state.value = mutableStateOf().apply {
                addAll(_state.value.apply { it ->
                    it.potatoes = result.data!!.potatoes
                    it.isLoading = false
                    it.error = ""
                })
            }
        }
    }
    is Resource.Error   -> {
        _state.value = mutableStateOf().apply {
            addAll(_state.value.apply { it ->
                it.error =
                    result.message ?:
                        "An unexpected error occurred"
                it.isLoading = false
            })
        }
    }
    is Resource.Loading -> {
        _state.value = mutableStateOf().apply {
            addAll(_state.value.apply { it ->
                it.isLoading = true
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh it really works as you say, I commented error and isLoading cases But what if I want to detect the error or the isLoading?

Comment: You probably would need to use a `class` without the `data` keyword.
That would give you the ability to define class properties with `var` instead of `val`.
Then you only need to assign new values to `PotatoesState` object's properties without creating a new instance.
That'll give you the chance to keep current data in the same object until you have other data to replace it with.

Comment: Well, this does not work... I remove ```data``` keyword in ```PotatoesState```, and in ```PotatoesViewModel``` in ```success case```, I put:
```_state.value.potatoes = result.data?.potatoes ?: emptyList()```

But now the list are empty always, in the screen does not show nothing.

Comment: @Paul9999 Never pass an `emptyList()` unless you want to show a blank list on purpose!
Check `if (result.data != null && result.data.potatoes != null)` and then pass the data only if it's not null.
Also, try using `_state.value = mutableListOf().apply{ addAll(_state.value.apply { result.data!!.potatoes })}`

Comment: I don't think I understand how it should look. I have made these changes and it is still empty:

``` 
class PotatoesState(
    var isLoading: Boolean = false,
    var potatoes: List<Potatoes> = emptyList(),
    var error: String = ""
)
```

```
 when (result) {
    is Response.Success -> {
        if (result.data != null) {
            _state.value.incidents = result.data.incidents
        }
    }
    ...            
```

Comment: I have edited  my answer to include the code I'd use